# CSS Grid всё съехало после добавления <!DOCTYPE html>

Tags: html, css, grid, doctype

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После добавления тега " <!DOCTYPE html>" row из grid съехали, из-за чего это может быть, я указывал всего 2 строки `grid-template-rows: 80% 20%;`, без доктайпа всё работало, а тут всё съехало, подскажите пожалуйста, что может быть, и как с этим бороться.

вот сайт http://322fa21ac077.ngrok.io/

Comment: какой раньше был доктип?

Comment: Раньше его вообще не было, по глупости верстал без доктипа

Answer (score 2):

Если вы будете пользоваться неполным тегом `DOCTYPE`, устаревшим его видом, или вообще забудете про него, браузер перейдет в *загадочный* (*quirk*) режим и будет исходить из предположения, что Вы писали код страницы с ошибками и вольно отступали от стандартов, т.е. так, как писали в конце 90-ых годов.

В этом режиме браузер попытается разобрать вашу страницу по правилам обратной совместимости и выведет на экран, например, **css** так, как его вывел бы *Internet Explorer* 8-ой версии, а **DOM** будет работать так, как он работал именно в этом браузере (*IE* переключается в свой старый **DOM**, аналогично и для остальных браузеров).